# How to get the caret's position in contentEditable div when entering a new line?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, uiwebview, contenteditable

I am making a rich text editor with UIWebview, which uses a `contentEditable` div. I want to get the caret's position in pixels. I have searched a lot, and I got the code below.

```
function getCaretClientPosition() {
  var x = 0, y = 0;
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  if (sel.rangeCount) {
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    if (range.getClientRects) {
      var rects = range.getClientRects();
      if (rects.length > 0) {
        x = rects[0].left;
        y = rects[0].top;
      }
    }
  }
  return { x: x, y: y };
}
```

The code above works well until I enter a newline. `sel.getRangeAt(0)` returns null, so the function can't return the right caret Y pixels.

Comment: `sel.getRangeAt(0)` is surprising. An example might help.

Comment: @Tim Downhttp://jsfiddle.net/timdown/xMEjD/

Comment: @Tim Down  I found a solution which you write, http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/xMEjD/ this code work well on IE, but not on safari, when you set cursor on the end of a line, and then click "Enter" key,the cursor goes the beginng of next line, but the cursor's y position in pixels is "0",

Comment: When the selection range doesn't give you a position, you may have to fall back to the tactic of inserting a temporary element at the caret position, getting the element's position and removing it again.

Comment: @Tim Down How can I insert the element and remove it, sorry Tim Down, I am new to javascript, Can you give me a demo?

Comment: @Tim Down Can you give me a example?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code I am using to get the caret's top position by inserting a temp object and remove it:

```
function getCaretTopPosition() {
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<span id="hidden"></span>');
    var hiddenNode = document.getElementById('hidden');
    if (!hiddenNode) {
        return 0;
    }
    var topPosition = hiddenNode.offsetTop;
    hiddenNode.parentNode.removeChild(hiddenNode);
    return topPosition;
}
```

Comment: In a UIWebView (iOS), this code inserts blank line, and prevent the caret from blinking...

Answer (score 1):

This solution fixes the newLine issue in WebKit.

```
function getCaretClientPosition() {
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {

        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        var needsToWorkAroundNewlineBug = (range.startContainer.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'p'
                                           && range.startOffset == 0);

        if (needsToWorkAroundNewlineBug) {
            x = range.startContainer.offsetLeft;
            y = range.startContainer.offsetTop;
        } else {
            if (range.getClientRects) {
                var rects = range.getClientRects();
                if (rects.length > 0) {
                    x = rects[0].left;
                    y = rects[0].top;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return { x: x, y: y };
}
```